# ERROR: syntax error at end of input, Java - Postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have used the next SQL statement but it fails in PostgreSQL.

```
sentencia.execute("INSERT INTO \"Registros\" (accion,num_tarjeta,valor,fecha_accion_ano,fecha_accion_mes,fecha_accion_dia) VALUES ('recarga','" + num_tarjeta + "','" + valor_recargar + "','" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + "','" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + "','" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "'");
```

with this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at end of input
```

What's the problem? Thanks

Comment: The *main* problem is that you're specifying a value directly in SQL. *Don't do that.* Use parameterized SQL instead, to separate the code from the data. Once you've fixed that, you'll see the syntax error much more easily... as well as not being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Additionally, you're calling `Calendar.getInstance()` multiple times, which means you could be using multiple different values. Imagine if you're executing this *right* at the end of the year... you could end up with the "old" year but the "new" month and day values. Ick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a `)` at the end of the statement and the table is surrounded with double quotes for no reason..

`sentencia.execute("INSERT INTO Registros (accion,num_tarjeta,valor,fecha_accion_ano,fecha_accion_mes,fecha_accion_dia) VALUES ('recarga','','','','','')");`